# Number, toc & heading tree glossary subentries

Tags: sectioning, glossaries

I use some glossaries, one in the main matter of my text, other in the back matter of my document. I applied to the first a homemade style with hierarchical entries & subentries (cf. MWE). I would trait differently both glossaries, but I'm exposed to the following difficulties:

When I decided to set a configuration in the announcement of the package, I don't know how to change. I want `\usepackage[numberedsection=autolabel]{glossaries}` for the first glossary, `\usepackage[section,numberedsection=nameref]{glossaries}` for the other.

Secondly, I want to number my hierarchical sub-entries like sections, subsections or subsubsections, and appear in toc and headings. But, if I try my own glossary style with an unstarred sectioning, compilation doesn't work.

```
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode 
% !TEX TS-program = arara
\documentclass{scrbook} 
\usepackage[xindy={language=french, codepage=utf8}]{glossaries}
\newglossary*{his}{History}
\newglossary*{est}{Esthetic}
\makeglossaries

\newglossarystyle{arbre}{%
\renewenvironment{theglossary}{\tablehead{}\begin{description}}{\end{description}\tabletail{}}%
\renewcommand{\glossaryheader}{}%
\renewcommand*{\glsgroupskip}{}%
\renewcommand*{\glossentry}[2]{\section*{\glsentryitem{##1}\glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}}}}% I want unscarred this \section
\renewcommand{\subglossentry}[3]{%
\ifnum##1=1\relax\subsection*{\glssubentryitem{##2}\glstarget{##2}{\glossentryname{##2}}}\fi% idem
\ifnum##1=2\relax\subsubsection*{\glssubentryitem{##2}\glstarget{##2}{\glossentryname{##2}}}\fi% idem
\ifnum##1=3\relax\item[\glssubentryitem{##2}\glstarget{##2}{\glossentryname{##2}}] \space\glossentrydesc{##2}\glspostdescription\space ##3\fi}}

\newglossaryentry{section}{type=est,name=section,description={\nopostdesc}}
\newglossaryentry{subsection}{type=est,name=subsection,parent=section,description={\nopostdesc}}
\newglossaryentry{subsubsection}{type=est,name=subsubsection,parent=subsection,description={\nopostdesc}}
\newglossaryentry{glouglou}{type=est,name=glouglou,parent=subsubsection,description={dindon}}
\newglossaryentry{coincoin}{type=his,name=coincoin,description={canard}}

\newcommand\est[5]{
\newglossaryentry{#1}{type=est,name=#1,description={\nopostdesc}}% 
\newglossaryentry{#2}{type=est,name=#2,parent=#1,description={\nopostdesc}}%
\newglossaryentry{#3}{type=est,name=#3,parent=#2,description={\nopostdesc}}% 
\newglossaryentry{#4}{type=est,name=#4,parent=#3,description={#5}}%
\gls{#4}, #5}%

\begin{document}
\est{section}{subsection}{subsubsection}{coco}{ara}, \gls{coincoin}, \gls{glouglou}.
\printglossary[type=est,style=arbre] 
% and now usepackage[section,numberedsection=nameref]{glossaries}
\printglossary[type=his]
\end{document}
% arara: xelatex
% arara: makeglossaries
% arara: xelatex
```

Thanks for your help. (This question is the continuation of [Glossaries with more hierarchical categories](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/316881/glossaries-with-more-hierarchical-categories/317223#317223))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `\setupglossaries` to modify some (*but not all*) of the settings that can be used in the package options. Fortunately the settings you want adjusted may be changed in the document. First with

```
\setupglossaries{numberedsection=autolabel}
```

and then with

```
\setupglossaries{section,numberedsection=nameref}
```

Modified MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrbook} 
\usepackage[xindy={language=french, codepage=utf8}]{glossaries}
\newglossary*{his}{History}
\newglossary*{est}{Esthetic}
\makeglossaries

\newglossarystyle{arbre}{%
\renewenvironment{theglossary}{\tablehead{}\begin{description}}{\end{description}\tabletail{}}%
\renewcommand{\glossaryheader}{}%
\renewcommand*{\glsgroupskip}{}%
\renewcommand*{\glossentry}[2]{\section*{\glsentryitem{##1}\glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}}}}% I want unscarred this \section
\renewcommand{\subglossentry}[3]{%
\ifnum##1=1\relax\subsection*{\glssubentryitem{##2}\glstarget{##2}{\glossentryname{##2}}}\fi% idem
\ifnum##1=2\relax\subsubsection*{\glssubentryitem{##2}\glstarget{##2}{\glossentryname{##2}}}\fi% idem
\ifnum##1=3\relax\item[\glssubentryitem{##2}\glstarget{##2}{\glossentryname{##2}}] \space\glossentrydesc{##2}\glspostdescription\space ##3\fi}}

\newglossaryentry{section}{type=est,name=section,description={\nopostdesc}}
\newglossaryentry{subsection}{type=est,name=subsection,parent=section,description={\nopostdesc}}
\newglossaryentry{subsubsection}{type=est,name=subsubsection,parent=subsection,description={\nopostdesc}}
\newglossaryentry{glouglou}{type=est,name=glouglou,parent=subsubsection,description={dindon}}
\newglossaryentry{coincoin}{type=his,name=coincoin,description={canard}}

\newcommand\est[5]{
\newglossaryentry{#1}{type=est,name=#1,description={\nopostdesc}}% 
\newglossaryentry{#2}{type=est,name=#2,parent=#1,description={\nopostdesc}}%
\newglossaryentry{#3}{type=est,name=#3,parent=#2,description={\nopostdesc}}% 
\newglossaryentry{#4}{type=est,name=#4,parent=#3,description={#5}}%
\gls{#4}, #5}%

\begin{document}
\setupglossaries{numberedsection=autolabel}
\est{section}{subsection}{subsubsection}{coco}{ara}, \gls{coincoin}, \gls{glouglou}.
\printglossary[type=est,style=arbre] 
\setupglossaries{section,numberedsection=nameref}
\printglossary[type=his]
\end{document}
```

Edit: for numbered sections in the glossary style, you'll need to use the optional argument of `\section` to overcome expansion problems and other unwanted stuff getting into the `.toc` file:

```
\renewcommand*{\glossentry}[2]{\section[\glsentryname{##1}]{\glsentryitem{##1}\glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}}}}
\renewcommand{\subglossentry}[3]{%
\ifnum##1=1\relax\subsection[\glsentryname{##2}]{\glssubentryitem{##2}\glstarget{##2}{\glossentryname{##2}}}\fi% idem
\ifnum##1=2\relax\subsubsection[\glsentryname{##2}]{\glssubentryitem{##2}\glstarget{##2}{\glossentryname{##2}}}\fi% idem
\ifnum##1=3\relax\item[\glssubentryitem{##2}\glstarget{##2}{\glossentryname{##2}}] \space\glossentrydesc{##2}\glspostdescription\space ##3\fi}
```

Comment: You are always my hero. I can't help but put two or three questions per article… sorry. What about the second question? Should I open another page & republish it (for ease)? Because this title matches more with my second question :s

Comment: @Zouib sorry, I missed that. I've edited my answer.

Comment: Great ! It run for `\section`, not for `\subsection` or `\subsubsection`. I still try tomorrow.

Comment: @Zouib Sorry, I forgot to add the edits to `\subglossentry`. I've updated my answer.